# Unable to send files to trash in hard drive. "File1 can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?" option coming

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, trash

I have a hard drive(NTFS) which is shared between my dual booted ubuntu and windows 11. he problem is when I try to delete something in hard drive it asks to permanently delete. But in /home, I am able to move files to trash.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is a normal behavior. NTFS belongs to Windows, and it has its own way to handle trash, moving the file into the trash folder. And  Ubuntu and its file system ext4 has a different method of handling trash, moving the inode of the file to the trash, allowing the space occupied by the file to be rewritten by other files.

Since these methods work only in their native file systems, trashing a file in NTFS on Ubuntu utilizes the only method to remove a file, permanently deleting.

Comment: I don't think there is no fix/workaround for that..

Comment: Shouldn't matter. If the user is allowed to write to the file system, it should create a directory called `.Trash-$UID` in its root directory and place any deleted files there.